# Remove a leading space from a range

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

I have a column range of about 500 rows. Most of those cells are stored as text. I populate a listbox on a userform with the values from that range. When a user selects one of those values from the listbox an event will find the value on the same row from another column using Index and Match and display it in a label on the userform. I get an error when selecting one of the few cells in the listbox that are not stored as text in the range because there is a leading space. I am assuming that the populated listbox automatically removes leading spaces from any cells in the range. Therefore, when it tries to find value 12345 from the listbox, for example, in the range it can't find it because the range contains (space)12345. I have tried:

```
Public Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim arr() As Variant
Dim rNum As Range

Const sNum As String = "Number"

Me.EnableEvents = False

wsName = "Report"
Set curWb = ActiveWorkbook
Set pReport = curWb.Worksheets(wsName)
Set pTable = pReport.ListObjects("tableName")

With pReport
    If .AutoFilterMode = True Then .ShowAllData
    .Cells.Rows.Hidden = False
    .Cells.Columns.Hidden = False
End With

Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction

With pTable
    Set rNum = .ListColumns(.ListColumns(sNum).Range.column).DataBodyRange
End With

-- HERE is where I tried all my implementations without success

arr = wf.Transpose(pReport.Range(rNum.address).Value)

Call BubbleSort(arr)

frmIssues.lstIssues1.List = arr

lstIssues1.ListStyle = 1
lstIssues2.ListStyle = 1
lstIssues1.MultiSelect = 2
lstIssues2.MultiSelect = 2
txtFocus.SetFocus

Me.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub lstIssues1_Change()

Dim rNum As Range
Dim rTitle As Range
Dim strResult As String
Dim intIndex As Integer
Dim intCount As Integer

Const sNum As String = "Number"
Const sTitle As String = "Title"

If EnableEvents = False Then Exit Sub

With lstIssues1
    For intIndex = 0 To .ListCount - 1
        If .Selected(intIndex) Then intCount = intCount + 1
    Next
End With

If intCount = 1 Then
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    wsName = "Report"
    Set curWb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set pReport = curWb.Worksheets(wsName)
    Set pTable = pReport.ListObjects("tableName")

    With pTable
        Set rNum = .ListColumns(.ListColumns(sNum).Range.column).DataBodyRange
        Set rTitle = .ListColumns(.ListColumns(sTitle).Range.column).DataBodyRange
    End With

    With pReport
        strResult = wf.Index(.Range(rTitle.address), wf.Match(lstIssues1.List(lstIssues1.ListIndex), .Range(rNum.address), 0))
    End With

    lblDescription.Caption = wf.Trim(strResult)
    txtFocus.SetFocus
Else
    lblDescription.Caption = ""
    txtFocus.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
End If

Me.EnableEvents = False

For i = 0 To lstIssues2.ListCount - 1
    If lstIssues2.Selected(i) = True Then lstIssues2.Selected(i) = False
Next

Me.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

and numerous variations of it (Clean, CStr, .Text, etc.) and nothing works. Truly, I have no clue how to fix this and any help whatsoever is much appreciated. Thank you!

**Clarification**

1) This Excel file is generated from the Web.

2) A Macro turns the Worksheet into a table

3) `Left(Range("D362"),1)` returns `1` (The number, say, is 12345)

4) Before the error occurs `Range("D362")` returns `(space)12345`

5) After the error occurs `Range("D362")` returns `(space)12345`

Comment: Should the cells in the column contain **numerals** only **??**

Comment: @Gary'sStudent No, there are about 20 rows or so that start with a letter. The majority of the cells, including the text ones, work. Only the ones not stored as text do not.

Comment: Depending on the variable type of 'item' I suspect that your TRIM()/REPLACE() functions are not working. If item is a range (a single cell), which seems likely from the Range(item.address), you need to work on item.Value

Comment: @PaaquaGrant `item` is a `Variant`. I have worked with `.Value` as well and that doesn't work. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Have you tried using replace on other characters not otherwise removed by TRIM(), such as Char(160) [a non-breaking space]?

Comment: I ran to this problem as well lately (not .value, trim, clean  functions work -neither combining them-). I had to do a workaround for that with replace function prior to re find the data. Cells.Replace What:=" ", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart

Comment: @PaaquaGrant I tried `Range(item.address).Value = Replace(item, Chr(160), "")` but it didn't work. Another good suggestion, though.

Comment: what about using a loop and Asc() to determine what character(s) is(are) actually there (in the problem strings)? What is the string of text being returned by TRIM/REPLACE?

Comment: @PaaquaGrant I printed the Asc() values to the immediate window and it doesn't show a space. It just gives the Ascii value for each of the 7 numerals.

Comment: I think we need to see more of the code that is running. Where is 'rngIssueNumber' being populated from? What function are you using to find the value chosen in your list box? When are the values in the range being modified as you suggest (between point 3 and 4 in your clarification)?

Comment: The additional code you provided does not explain how a space (or other extraneous character) is being added to the non-alpha cells. Perhaps the key lies in the BubbleSort sub?

Comment: For reference, Ascii characters 1, 9, 10, 28, 29, 30, 31, 129, 141, 143, 144, 157, and 160 are all either invisible or appear as spaces of various lengths, and none of them are removed by Trim(). Are you sure your table doesn't contain any of these characters?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113759/discussion-between-paaqua-grant-and-brian).

Comment: I am unable to use chat at the moment. I will be able to in a few hours. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

I have just tested this and it works in removing the space at the begining of a string. Sadly it isnt a single line as I (and likely you) would have prefered

```
Sub test()

Dim CellValue As String
Dim lngNumberOfCharacters As Long

CellValue = ActiveCell.Value
CellValueCheck = Left(CellValue, 1)

If CellValueCheck = " " Then
lngNumberOfCharacters = Len(CellValue) - 1

CellValue = Right(CellValue, lngNumberOfCharacters)
ActiveCell.Value = CellValue
End If

End Sub
```

Let me know if you need anything confirmed

Comment: Thank you for the post but it doesn't work. It does not recognize a space even though it shows up when trying to find it in the range. I read something in SO about Excel reserving a space for a `#` when converting from text but I can't find it.

Comment: When I tried it on Excel 2010 it worked perfectly fine, you are using excel 2013 so shouldnt be an issue with the code. If you do `CellValue = ActiveCell.Value` does it show a space at the begining of the string?

Comment: `ActiveCell.Value` does not show a space at the beginning of the string. I indicated that in my Clarification update at the top. I also recently added more code to help give more insight to those trying to help. :-)